# Proc SGplot Including trend line

Tags: sas

When I use proc sgplot to plot individual subject lines based on predicted values for some reason t is also connecting the first point and last point of each subject which is making the plot incredibly hard to look at.  Any help on removing the trend line would be helpful.
Code  below:

```
proc sgplot data=means;
series x=F9 y=pred / group=eaton grouplc=count;
run;
quit;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFfws.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to sort your X-values first, before running proc sgplot.

Comment: Thanks for the input, just tried it but now my graph looks like this:                                   
      [new plot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLDW8.png

Comment: Can you include some samples rows from the `means` table?

Comment: I can't recreate your issue without data, but you might want to try using the `vline` statement instead.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  Unfortunately I can't post the data but it is the predicted values given from proc mixed.  It has to be something to do with my graphics setting, because it is correctly plotting the averages at each time point, the issue is that it is also including a line from each baseline to 24 week period.